# Exceptions while running Cucumber Tests

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to run a script in Eclipse using Firefox driver and selenium using Cucumber Gherkin format for BDD. I am getting a lot of exceptions when I run this on Junit this is my code as follows for the Java file.

annotation.java

```
package annotation; 

import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 

import cucumber.annotation.en.Given; 
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then; 
import cucumber.annotation.en.When; 

public class annotation { 
   WebDriver driver = null; 
   @Given("^I am on Facebook login page$") 

   public void goToFacebook() { 
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
      driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/"); 
   }

   @When("^I enter username as \"(.*)\"$") 
   public void enterUsername(String arg1) {   
      driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(arg1); 
   }

   @When ("^I enter password as \"(.*)\"$") 
   public void enterPassword(String arg1) {
      driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(arg1);
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_v")).click(); 
   } 

   @Then("^Login should fail$") 
   public void checkFail() {  
      if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(
         "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")){ 
            System.out.println("Test1 Pass"); 
      } else { 
         System.out.println("Test1 Failed"); 
      } 
      driver.close(); 
   }

   @Then("^Relogin option should be available$") 
   public void checkRelogin() { 
      if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(
         "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")){ 
            System.out.println("Test2 Pass"); 
      } else { 
         System.out.println("Test2 Failed"); 
      } 
      driver.close(); 
   }
}
```

These are the exceptions that I am receiving once I execute the test

> Feature: annotation
>
> #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
>   Background:  [90m# annotation\outline.feature:4[0m
>        User navigates to Facebook Given 
>        I am on Facebook login page
>
> #Scenario with AND   Scenario:                         [90m#
>   annotation\outline.feature:9[0m
>       [90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m  [90m#
>   annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m [1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI
>   enter username as "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m  [90m#
>   annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
>         [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
>             at annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
>             at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:10)
>         [0m
>       [90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m [90m#
>   annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m [1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter
>   password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m [90m#
>   annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
>       [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m [1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should
>   fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
>
> #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
>   Background:  [90m# annotation\outline.feature:4[0m
>        User navigates to Facebook Given 
>        I am on Facebook login page
>
> #Scenario with BUT   Scenario:                                [90m#
>   annotation\outline.feature:15[0m
>       [90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m         [90m#
>   annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m [1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI
>   enter username as "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m         [90m#
>   annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
>         [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
>             at annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
>             at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:16)
>         [0m
>       [90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m        [90m#
>   annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m [1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter
>   password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m        [90m#
>   annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
>       [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m                 [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m [1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should
>   fail[0m                 [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
>       [90mBut [0m[90mRelogin option should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m [1A    [36mBut [0m[36mRelogin option
>   should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)   at ✽.When I
>   enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:10)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)   at ✽.When I
>   enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:16)

This is my outline.feature file

```
Feature: annotation 
#This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps 

Background: 
   User navigates to Facebook Given 
   I am on Facebook login page 

#Scenario with AND 
Scenario: 
   When I enter username as "TOM"
   And I enter password as "JERRY" 
   Then Login should fail 

#Scenario with BUT 
Scenario: 
   When I enter username as "TOM" 
   And I enter password as "JERRY" 
   Then Login should fail 
   But Relogin option should be available
```

Comment: Does replacing `@Given("^I am on Facebook login page$")` with `@Before` fix the problem?

Comment: ...or adding `static` before `WebDriver driver = null;`?

Comment: Please show the `outline.feature`

Comment: Please share your feature file

Answer (score 1):

"Given" should be the first keyword on the line in the Background step, like so:

```
Background: User navigates to Facebook  
   Given I am on Facebook login page
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run your scenarios in my system.Can you share the dependency/jars you are using.
Also, driver.close() method in ***Then*** Statement (Login should fail ) will work fine for first scenario but in second scenario it would close the browser before the next ***Then*** (Relogin option should be available) statement.so you may want to remove that close method .